# ArrayList and Generics in Java

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, collections

Can I create an Arraylist like `ArrayList<Integer, Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<>();` in Java ?

What I actually require is store a pair at each element of an ArrayList and sort in non-decreasing order based on the first element of each pair.

For instance:

`(6,2)
 (2,8)
 (1,2)
 (4,5)`

should finally give :

`(1,2)
 (2,8)
 (4,5)
 (6,2)`

Comment: Create a class `Pair` with two `ints` and make a `List` out of that... For the comparison simply include `Comparable<Integer>`.

Comment: You can either use a `TreeMap<Integer, Integer>`, or an `ArrayList<YourTuple>` where `YourTuple` implements `Comparable<Integer>` and bases the implementation on comparison of the first integer.

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to use a [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), which would sort the values of type `Integer` without you doing any extra work:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put(6, 2);
map.put(2, 8);
map.put(1, 2);
map.put(4, 5);
```

Printing it like so:

```
map.entrySet().stream().forEach((entry) -> {
    System.out.println("(" + entry.getKey() + "," + entry.getValue()+")");    
});
```

produces:

> (1,2)
>
> (2,8)
>
> (4,5)
>
> (6,2)

Or perhaps as mentioned elsewhere, create your own class and sort it manually.

Comment: The `Treemap` works  but not in any case as keys are unique in a Map.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot create list like this. You can use map to solve this problem but this solution let you store only 1 element with first value cause in maps key is unique so I suggest  to create your own class with 2 fields as needed and create arraylist of that object

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. `ArrayList` takes only one type variable which denotes the type of the elements it has.

For your need, you can create a `Pair` class or use a `Pair` implementation that comes from some library and add it to the list. Then you can define a comparator for sorting the list.

Answer (score 1):

Create another class Pair that holds two integers

```
    class Pair{
        int first;
        int last;
        etc...
```

To order them, implement Comparable and use a data structure such as a priorityQueue

Comment: "To order them, implement Comparable" Not necessarily with a `Comparator` but upvote whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pair Object with following code

```
    ArrayList<javafx.util.Pair<Integer, Integer>> arrList  = new ArrayList<>();
    arrList.add(new Pair<>(6,2));
    arrList.add(new Pair<>(2,8));
    arrList.add(new Pair<>(1,2));
    arrList.add(new Pair<>(4,5));

    arrList.sort(java.util.Comparator.comparing(Pair::getKey));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ArrayList` of type `Integer[]` and then sort it by the index of the element you want.

(`ArrayList<Integer[]> list = new ArrayList();`)